# Reloj en javascript se duplica

Tags: javascript

Quise crear un reloj que los números estén formados por asteriscos, y al momento de imprimir el reloj, se actualiza pero de forma vertical, haciendo que haya más de un reloj.
Lo que debería realizar es un solo reloj y que se actualice cada segundo pero no lo hace.
Agregué todo en una sola función *Myfunc*, la cual la llama a la variable *crono* que se ejecuta con un `setInterval`, pero de igual forma no hace lo requerido.

Quizás ahí nazca el problemma, ya que no sé dónde inicia el `setInterval`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <script>
    var cero = [2, 3, 4, 6, 10, 11, 15, 16, 20, 22, 23, 24]
    var uno = [3, 7, 8, 13, 18, 22, 23, 24]
    var dos = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
    var tres = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
    var cuatro = [1, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 25]
    var cinco = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
    var seis = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
    var siete = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21]
    var ocho = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
    var nueve = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
    var punto = [8, 18]


    function myFunc() {

      var miReloj = new Date();


      //Horas del reloj
      var hora = miReloj.getHours();
      var arregloh = hora.toString().split("")
      var numeroh = parseInt(arregloh[0])
      var numerohb = parseInt(arregloh[1])

      if (hora < 10) {
        var hora = miReloj.getHours();
        var arregloh = hora.toString().split("")
        arregloh[1] = "0";
        var invertirh = arregloh.reverse()
        var numeroh = invertirh[0]
        var numerohb = invertirh[1]
      }
      arreglob = convertir(numeroh)
      arregloc = convertir(numerohb)


      //minutos del reloj
      var minuto = miReloj.getMinutes();
      var arreglom = minuto.toString().split("")
      var numerom = parseInt(arreglom[0])
      var numeromb = parseInt(arreglom[1])
      var invertir = arreglom.reverse()

      if (minuto < 10) {
        var minuto = miReloj.getUTCMinutes();
        var arreglom = minuto.toString().split("")
        arreglom[1] = "0";
        var invertirm = arreglom.reverse()
        var numerom = invertirm[0]
        var numeromb = invertirm[1]
      }

      arreglod = convertir(numerom)
      arregloe = convertir(numeromb)

      //Segundos del reloj
      var segundo = miReloj.getSeconds();
      var arreglos = segundo.toString().split("")
      var numeros = parseInt(arreglos[0])
      var numerosb = parseInt(arreglos[1])


      if (segundo < 10) {
        var segundo = miReloj.getSeconds();
        var arreglos = segundo.toString().split("")
        arreglos[1] = "0";
        var invertirs = arreglos.reverse()
        var numeros = invertirs[0]
        var numerosb = invertirs[1]
      }

      arreglof = convertir(numeros)
      arreglog = convertir(numerosb)





      for (var x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {

        //HORAS
        for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
          if (y % 6 == 0) {
            document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
            continue
          }
          if (y > 6) {
            z = y % 6
          } else {
            z = y
          }
          if (arreglob.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
            document.write("*")
          } else {
            document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
          }
        }

        for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
          if (y % 6 == 0) {
            document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
            continue
          }
          if (y > 6) {
            z = y % 6
          } else {
            z = y
          }
          if (arregloc.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
            document.write("*")
          } else {
            document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
          }
        }

        //PUNTOS

        for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
          if (y % 6 == 0) {
            document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
            continue
          }
          if (y > 6) {
            z = y % 6
          } else {
            z = y
          }
          if (punto.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
            document.write("*")
          } else {
            document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
          }
        }

        //MINUTOS

        for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
          if (y % 6 == 0) {
            document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
            continue
          }
          if (y > 6) {
            z = y % 6
          } else {
            z = y
          }
          if (arreglod.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
            document.write("*")
          } else {
            document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
          }
        }

        for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
          if (y % 6 == 0) {
            document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
            continue
          }
          if (y > 6) {
            z = y % 6
          } else {
            z = y
          }
          if (arregloe.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
            document.write("*")
          } else {
            document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
          }
        }

        //PUNTOS

        for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
          if (y % 6 == 0) {
            document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
            continue
          }
          if (y > 6) {
            z = y % 6
          } else {
            z = y
          }
          if (punto.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
            document.write("*")
          } else {
            document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
          }
        }

        //SEGUNDOS

        for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
          if (y % 6 == 0) {
            document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
            continue
          }
          if (y > 6) {
            z = y % 6
          } else {
            z = y
          }
          if (arreglof.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
            document.write("*")
          } else {
            document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
          }
        }

        for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
          if (y % 6 == 0) {
            document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
            continue
          }
          if (y > 6) {
            z = y % 6
          } else {
            z = y
          }
          if (arreglog.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
            document.write("*")
          } else {
            document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
          }
        }


        document.write("<br>")
      }
    }


    var crono = setInterval(myFunc, 1000);

    function convertir(numeroc) {
      switch (numeroc) {

        case 0:
          return cero;
          break;
        case "0":
          return cero;
          break;
        case 1:
          return uno;
          break;
        case "1":
          return uno;
          break;
        case 2:
          return dos;
          break;
        case "2":
          return dos;
          break;
        case 3:
          return tres;
          break;
        case "3":
          return tres;
          break;
        case 4:
          return cuatro;
          break;
        case "4":
          return cuatro;
          break;
        case 5:
          return cinco;
          break;
        case "5":
          return cinco;
          break;
        case 6:
          return seis;
          break;
        case "6":
          return seis;
          break;
        case 7:
          return siete;
          break;
        case "7":
          return siete;
          break;
        case 8:
          return ocho;
          break;
        case "8":
          return ocho;
          break;
        case 9:
          return nueve;
          break;
        case "9":
          return nueve;
          break;
        default:
          return 0;
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Dentro de tu función `myFunc` antes de `var miReloj = new Date();` coloca `document.body.innerHTML="";` y así limpias la pantalla

Comment: Java != Javascript :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estas limpiando la pantalla o elemento, con lo que con cada "window.write" se escriben nuevos datos.

En vez de usar "window.write", coloca un "div" en el "body" con un "id", y llamalo así;

```
var idDiv = document.getElementById("tuid");
```

Luego cambia el valor así al inicio de la función;

```
idDiv.innerHTML = "";
```

Luego reemplaza cada "window.write", por;

```
idDiv.innerHTML += lo_que_quieras_imprimir;
```

Por último, las variables "var" se definen una única vez, con lo que NO es mecesario que lo hagas cada 2 líneas de código.

Saludos.

Comment: bro , no te entendi mucho jaja , podrias explicarte mejor por favor , que es un proyecto de universidad el que debo presentar

Comment: Hoy por hoy, solo en casos especiales se utiliza `var`: se utilizan en su lugar `let` y `const`. Ver: [¿Cuándo conviene utilizar var, let y const en ECMA Script 6?](/q/56116)

Comment: No precisamente en caso especiales, sino que "let" sería en el ámbito de una función por ejemplo, para no comprometer a variables con mismo nombre fuera de esa función. "const" es una variable que no se modifica y "var" es una variable que se puede acceder desde casi cualquier lado. Maycol, intenta releer mi respuesta y entender lo que estas haciendo, ya que no estas entendiendo los conceptos de cada parte de tu código.

Comment: muchas gracias , al final pude lograr que funcione .

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no limpias la pantalla luego de cada intervalo.

Usar `document.write` dificulta esta limpieza, además que esta función raramente se utiliza. Lo habitual es usar un `div` y editar su contenido con `innerHTML`

Por ejemplo

```js
const divReloj = document.getElementById("reloj");
divReloj.innerHTML ="08:23:23";
```

```html
<div id="reloj"></div>
```

Tu idea para generar el reloj es bastante buena, pero la implementación se puede mejorar bastante, te dejo algunas recomendaciones:

1.- Tienes 10 arrays de números (del 0 al 9), si cambias a un array de arrays (llamémosle `numeros`), y te aprovechas de la posición te ahorras la función `convertir` que tiene un switch enorme. En esa función tu buscas el array correspondiente según un número de entrada (`numeroc`). Si usas mi recomendación solo tienes que hacer `numeros[numeroc]`

2.- Rescatas la hora obteniendo cada parte (hora, minuto, segundo) y en entero, por lo que no tienes el cero a la izquierda en los números menores a 10. Si usas la función `toLocaleTimeString` obtienes un string inmediatamente en formato `02:01:03` y puedes recorrerlo con un `for(let caracter of hora)`

3.- Luego para imprimir el número utilizas repetidamente una logica como esta:

```
for(var y=1;y<=6;y++){
  if(y%6==0){
      document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
      continue
  }
  if(y>6){
      z=y%6
  }else{
      z=y
  }
  if(punto.includes(5*(x-1)+z)){
      document.write("*")
  }else{
      document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
  }
}
```

Cuando tu tienes un código que se repite muchas veces es señal que debes pasar aquel código a otra función para reciclarla.

Además este código no tiene mucha lógica

- `y%6==0` solo se cumple en la última iteración, perfectamente puedes sacarla del for y colocarla abajo de él
- `y>6` Esta condición nunca se va a cumplir

Así quedaría:

```js
const numeros =[[2,3,4,6,10,11,15,16,20,22,23,24],
[3,7,8,13,18,22,23,24],
[1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,21,22,23,24,25],
[1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12,13,14,15,20,21,22,23,24,25],
[1,5,6,10,11,12,13,14,15,20,25],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13,14,15,20,21,22,23,24,25],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13,14,15,16,20,21,22,23,24,25],
[1,2,3,4,5,9,13,17,21],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20,21,22,23,24,25],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,12,13,14,15,20,21,22,23,24,25]];

const punto=[8,18];

//Esta función reemplaza a tu función `convertir`
function getArray(numeroc){
  if(numeroc == ":") return punto;
  return numeros[numeroc];
}

//Función que busca la  fila a imprimir del arreglo
function getLine(arreglo,y){
  let resp ="";
  for(var x=1;x<=5;x++){
    if(arreglo.includes(5 * (y-1) + x)){
        resp+="*";
    }else{
        resp+="&nbsp&nbsp";
    }
  }
  return resp+"&nbsp&nbsp" ;
}

function myFunc(){
  const miReloj = new Date();
  const horaString = miReloj.toLocaleTimeString();

  let salida="";
  for(var y=1;y<=5;y++){ //recorre las filas de la matriz que genera el reloj
    for(let n of horaString){ //recorre cada caracter de la hora (ej: 01:20:33) de izquierda a derecha
       const arrayNums = getArray(n);
       salida+=getLine(arrayNums,y);
    }
    salida+="<br>"; //salto de linea para imprimir la siguiente fila
  }

//imprime dentro del div con id "reloj" y en cada intervalo se pisa su valor por uno nuevo
reloj.innerHTML= salida;
}
const crono = setInterval(myFunc, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="reloj"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por estas indicaciones , mejorare más con eso y mejorar mi logica