# arbol y mensaje de navidad

Tags: javascript

quise crear un árbol y mensaje de "feliz navidad 2024", los cuales están formados por asteriscos, dentro de JavaScript, pero no logro juntar el mensaje y el árbol en una misma fila, siempre me sale uno arriba del otro, quisiera saber cómo puedo unir los dos.
ya intenté unir todo en mismo ciclo for , pero no imprime nada.
He creado tres ciclos for , uno para el mensaje que es el más grande, y los otros dos son el cuadrado y el triángulo.
lo que deseo que imprima es que el mensaje salga al lado izquierdo de las figuras que forman un arbol

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        
        <body>
            <script>
            var cero = [2, 3, 4, 6, 10, 11, 15, 16, 20, 22, 23, 24]
            var dos = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
            var cuatro = [1, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 25]
            var letf = [1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13,14,15,16,21]
            var lete = [1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13,14,15,16,21,22,23,24,25]
            var letl = [1,6,11,,16,21,22,23,24,25]
            var leti = [1,2,3,4,5,8,13,18,,21,22,23,24,25]
            var letz = [1,2,3,4,5,9,13,17,,21,22,23,24,25]
            var letn = [1,5,6,7,10,11,13,,15,16,19,,20,21,25]
            var leta = [2,3,4,6,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20,21,25]
            var letv = [1,5,6,10,12,14,18,23]
            var letd = [1,2,3,4,6,10,11,15,16,20,21,22,23,24]
        
        
        
        
            
        
        
        
        
              for (var x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
        
                //Feliz
                for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                  if (y % 6 == 0) {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                    continue
                  }
                  if (y > 6) {
                    z = y % 6
                  } else {
                    z = y
                  }
                  if (letf.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
                    document.write("*")
                  } else {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                  }
                }
        
                for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                  if (y % 6 == 0) {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                    continue
                  }
                  if (y > 6) {
                    z = y % 6
                  } else {
                    z = y
                  }
                  if (lete.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
                    document.write("*")
                  } else {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                  }
                }
        
                
                for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                  if (y % 6 == 0) {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                    continue
                  }
                  if (y > 6) {
                    z = y % 6
                  } else {
                    z = y
                  }
                  if (letl.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
                    document.write("*")
                  } else {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                  }
                }
        
                for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                  if (y % 6 == 0) {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                    continue
                  }
                  if (y > 6) {
                    z = y % 6
                  } else {
                    z = y
                  }
                  if (leti.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
                    document.write("*")
                  } else {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                  }
                }
        
                for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                  if (y % 6 == 0) {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                    continue
                  }
                  if (y > 6) {
                    z = y % 6
                  } else {
                    z = y
                  }
                  if (letz.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
                    document.write("*")
                  } else {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                  }
                }
        
                document.write("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp") //espacios 
        
                //2024
        
                for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                  if (y % 6 == 0) {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                    continue
                  }
                  if (y > 6) {
                    z = y % 6
                  } else {
                    z = y
                  }
                  if (dos.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
                    document.write("*")
                  } else {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                  }
                }
        
                for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                  if (y % 6 == 0) {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                    continue
                  }
                  if (y > 6) {
                    z = y % 6
                  } else {
                    z = y
                  }
                  if (cero.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
                    document.write("*")
                  } else {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                  }
                }
        
                for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                  if (y % 6 == 0) {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                    continue
                  }
                  if (y > 6) {
                    z = y % 6
                  } else {
                    z = y
                  }
                  if (dos.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
                    document.write("*")
                  } else {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                  }
                }
        
                for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                  if (y % 6 == 0) {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                    continue
                  }
                  if (y > 6) {
                    z = y % 6
                  } else {
                    z = y
                  }
                  if (cuatro.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
                    document.write("*")
                  } else {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                  }
                }
        
                document.write("<br>")
              }
        
              document.write("<br>")
        
        
              for (var x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
        
                for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                  if (y % 6 == 0) {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                    continue
                  }
                  if (y > 6) {
                    z = y % 6
                  } else {
                    z = y
                  }
                  if (letn.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
                    document.write("*")
                  } else {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                  }
                }
        
                for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                  if (y % 6 == 0) {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                    continue
                  }
                  if (y > 6) {
                    z = y % 6
                  } else {
                    z = y
                  }
                  if (leta.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
                    document.write("*")
                  } else {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                  }
                }
        
                for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                  if (y % 6 == 0) {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                    continue
                  }
                  if (y > 6) {
                    z = y % 6
                  } else {
                    z = y
                  }
                  if (letv.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
                    document.write("*")
                  } else {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                  }
                }
        
                for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                  if (y % 6 == 0) {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                    continue
                  }
                  if (y > 6) {
                    z = y % 6
                  } else {
                    z = y
                  }
                  if (leti.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
                    document.write("*")
                  } else {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                  }
                }
        
                for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                  if (y % 6 == 0) {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                    continue
                  }
                  if (y > 6) {
                    z = y % 6
                  } else {
                    z = y
                  }
                  if (letd.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
                    document.write("*")
                  } else {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                  }
                }
        
                for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                  if (y % 6 == 0) {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                    continue
                  }
                  if (y > 6) {
                    z = y % 6
                  } else {
                    z = y
                  }
                  if (leta.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
                    document.write("*")
                  } else {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                  }
                }
        
                for (var y = 1; y <= 6; y++) {
                  if (y % 6 == 0) {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                    continue
                  }
                  if (y > 6) {
                    z = y % 6
                  } else {
                    z = y
                  }
                  if (letd.includes(5 * (x - 1) + z)) {
                    document.write("*")
                  } else {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                  }
                }
                
                document.write("<br>")
              }
        
        
        
                //triangulo
        
                const alturaTriangulo = 10;
        
                // Bucle para cada fila del triángulo
                for (let i = 1; i <= alturaTriangulo; i++) {
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp")
                    let espacios = '&nbsp '.repeat(alturaTriangulo - i); // Añade espacios antes de los asteriscos
                    let asteriscos = '*'.repeat(i * 2 - 1); // Añade asteriscos
        
                    document.write(espacios + asteriscos + '<br>');
                }
        
        
                //cuadrado
        
                for (var x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
        
                    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp")
        
                    for (var y = 1; y <= 10; y++) {
                        document.write('*')
        
                    }
                    document.write("<br>")
                }
        
            </script>
        </body>
        
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta pregunta es casi lo mismo que tenias en tu otra pregunta del reloj y repites los mismos problemas.

La programación no es colocar una lista de comandos o instrucciones, de lo contario vas a terminar con un código de un millón de líneas.

Fíjate en mi [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/608752/301324) a tu otra pregunta, yo tomo ese código y con unas mínimas modificaciones ya tengo el 90% realizado, básicamente cambio el array de array, por un objeto a modo de diccionario

```js
const letras ={
 "0" :  [2, 3, 4, 6, 10, 11, 15, 16, 20, 22, 23, 24],
 "2" :  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 21, 22, 23],
 "4" :  [1, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 25],
 "a" :  [2,3,4,6,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20,21,25],
 "d" :  [1,2,3,4,6,10,11,15,16,20,21,22,23,24],
 "e" :  [1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13,14,15,16,21,22,23,24,25],
 "f" :  [1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13,14,15,16,21],
 "i" :  [1,2,3,4,5,8,13,18,,21,22,23,24,25],
 "l" :  [1,6,11,,16,21,22,23,24,25],
 "n" :  [1,5,6,7,10,11,13,,15,16,19,20,21,25],
 "v" :  [1,5,6,10,12,14,18,23],
 "z" :  [1,2,3,4,5,9,13,17,,21,22,23,24,25],
 " ":   [],
};


function getLine(arreglo,y){
  let resp ="";
  for(var x=1;x<=5;x++){
    if(arreglo.includes(5 * (y-1) + x)){
        resp+="*";
    }else{
        resp+="&nbsp&nbsp";
    }
  }
  return resp+"&nbsp&nbsp" ;
  
}

function Imprimir(texto){
  let salida="";
  for(var y=1;y<=5;y++){
    for(let n of texto){ 
       const arrayNums = letras[n];
       salida+=getLine(arrayNums,y);
    }
    salida+="<br>";
  }


textoCode.innerHTML+= salida;
}
Imprimir("feliz navidad");
```

```html
<div id="textoCode"></div>
```

---

Ahora el problema está en generar un árbol de navidad, para lo cual debes entender la lógica de lo que estas haciendo y en que radica tu problema.

Tu estas imprimiendo punto a punto, tal como lo hacían las impresoras antiguas, va de izquierda a derecha y luego baja a la siguiente línea.

Cada carácter le has dado una dimensión de una matriz de 5x5, es decir una línea tiene 5 puntos de alto.

Entonces tu no puedes imprimir el texto y el árbol de manera separada (al menos no de la manera que lo estas haciendo)

Lo que te recomiendo para crear un árbol que sea de mayor tamaño a una fila, es separar el árbol en partes y cada parte representa un carácter

Por ejemplo, un árbol formado por 9 (3x3) caracteres:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces hay que crear 9 array que representen cada parte y listo

```js
const letras ={
 "0" :  [2, 3, 4, 6, 10, 11, 15, 16, 20, 22, 23, 24],
 "2" :  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 21, 22, 23],
 "4" :  [1, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 25],
 "a" :  [2,3,4,6,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20,21,25],
 "d" :  [1,2,3,4,6,10,11,15,16,20,21,22,23,24],
 "e" :  [1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13,14,15,16,21,22,23,24,25],
 "f" :  [1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13,14,15,16,21],
 "i" :  [1,2,3,4,5,8,13,18,,21,22,23,24,25],
 "l" :  [1,6,11,,16,21,22,23,24,25],
 "n" :  [1,5,6,7,10,11,13,,15,16,19,20,21,25],
 "v" :  [1,5,6,10,12,14,18,23],
 "z" :  [1,2,3,4,5,9,13,17,,21,22,23,24,25],
 " ":   [],
 "➀" : [20,24,25],
 "➁" : [3,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25],
 "➂" : [16,21,22],
 "➃" : [3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
 "➄" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,18,19,22,23,24],
 "➅" : [1,2,3,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15],
 "➆" : [],
 "➇" : [2,3,4,7,8,9,12,13,14,17,18,19,22,23,24],
 "➈": []
};


function getLine(arreglo,y,l){
  let resp ="";
  for(var x=1;x<=5;x++){
    if(arreglo.includes(5 * (y-1) + x)){
        resp+="*";
    }else{
        resp+="&nbsp&nbsp";
    }
  }
  if(l.match(/[a-z0-9]| /i)){ //Separación entre caracteres
    return resp+"&nbsp&nbsp" ;
  }
  return resp ; //Cuando no es una letra o número, no habrá separación, así se puede imprimir dibujos compuestos
  
}

function Imprimir(texto){
  let salida="";
  for(var y=1;y<=5;y++){
    for(let n of texto){ 
       const arrayNums = letras[n];
       salida+=getLine(arrayNums,y,n);
    }
    salida+="<br>";
  }


textoCode.innerHTML+= salida;
}
Imprimir("              ➀➁➂");
Imprimir("feliz navidad ➃➄➅");
Imprimir("              ➆➇➈");
```

```html
<div id="textoCode"></div>
```